# Prevent wrist-injuries when doing curls with high weight

Tags: exercise, biceps, curls

I am doing 25 pound dumb bell curls for a while and now I'd like to move to 35 pounds. The problem is, that I am afraid that my wrist will get injured with that much weight.

Will wrist bands help or should I support my wrist with the other hand while taking up and letting down the weights?

Comment: Why are you afraid your wrist will get hurt? Has it been injured before?

Comment: @Alec when i do wrist curl i can hardly take 15 pound, if my wrist flex too much while carrying weight in curl it will get damaged like earlier

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not move up to 27.5 or 30lbs dumbbells?
2. Generally people hurt their wrists doing higher weight, more awkward wrist position types of presses *(i.e. Flat Bench Barbell)* .  With no previous injury history you're unlikely to hurt yourself with 25lbs dumbbells (just make sure you're in a position where you can drop them and they won't injure you or anyone else).
3. I'm assuming your gym has a Free Motion type of machine, if you're
   concerned switch to that for a while / do straight *(if your wrist
   gives out something you can let go of)*

   - See the following attachments:  Use them with an overhand and
     underhand grip *(supinated and pronated)*.  Should not take long for
     your wrist strength to catch up.

[image] 
[image]